# How to pass filename and file content to awk

Tags: bash, csv, awk, metaprogramming

### tl;dr

Does anyone know how to pass a filename and the rest of the content of the file to awk? And make it run through all files in the directory and append the output of those actions to 1 final file?

### long story:

I need to generate an SQL update file every week based on 2 variables and I used to copy paste a lot into a CSV file to get this awk command going. My setup is like this:

a very long manually pasted together CSV, row 1 looking something like this:

```
3afb6dad-352d-4c2a-b348-40fdb3c3d9a6;019f08dd-5017-43a1-b65b-c77cb90068ab
```

An AWK command that runs through the CSV:

```
cat list.csv  | awk -F\; '{print "update db01.CONTENT set locationid = \"" $1 "\" where cdbid = \"" $2 "\";";'}
```

I want to automate this by automatically generating that CSV file or even better by passing the right variables directly to the script.

I have several input files. The title of the file has to be `$1` in my awk command and is constant. The file itself contains a variable number of UUIDs which needs to be `$2`

#### Input

I have a file called `3afb6dad-352d-4c2a-b348-40fdb3c3d9a6`.  The contents of this file look something like this:

```
019f08dd-5017-43a1-b65b-c77cb90068ab 
0479c914-6988-4038-ac74-f5b4adb123d0 
05a6b05a-dff9-4f7c-8a7e-92c8651b8cde 
05ad4a6a-e2c6-4074-adfd-0899c15a3600 
204b12af-42d8-48a0-83c6-10e02a051ed5 
20c4fb93-6ed2-4dee-87da-749b52c76d74 
27b2552a-1050-47fb-96fe-714b4231a067 
343f34be-b1cf-4cdf-8c35-344847a13837
```

I have another file named `72d799e8-ff97-4388-a498-47badd6ca7d8` containing something like this:

```
54b0623f-b5f0-47a1-bf90-9c8cb2054676 
8056e400-b809-4e08-bf0a-d5370f3e1b44
```

#### Desired output

what I need is to get a .sql file containing:

```
 update db01.CONTENT set locationid="3afb6dad-352d-4c2a-b348-40fdb3c3d9a6" where cdbid ="019f08dd-5017-43a1-b65b-c77cb90068ab"; 
update db01.CONTENT set locationid ="3afb6dad-352d-4c2a-b348-40fdb3c3d9a6" where cdbid="0479c914-6988-4038-ac74-f5b4adb123d0"; 
update db01.CONTENT set locationid ="3afb6dad-352d-4c2a-b348-40fdb3c3d9a6" where cdbid="05a6b05a-dff9-4f7c-8a7e-92c8651b8cde"; 
update db01.CONTENT set locationid ="3afb6dad-352d-4c2a-b348-40fdb3c3d9a6" where cdbid="05ad4a6a-e2c6-4074-adfd-0899c15a3600"; 
update db01.CONTENT set locationid ="3afb6dad-352d-4c2a-b348-40fdb3c3d9a6" where cdbid="204b12af-42d8-48a0-83c6-10e02a051ed5"; 
update db01.CONTENT set locationid ="3afb6dad-352d-4c2a-b348-40fdb3c3d9a6" where cdbid="20c4fb93-6ed2-4dee-87da-749b52c76d74"; 
update db01.CONTENT set locationid ="3afb6dad-352d-4c2a-b348-40fdb3c3d9a6" where cdbid="27b2552a-1050-47fb-96fe-714b4231a067"; 
update db01.CONTENT set locationid ="3afb6dad-352d-4c2a-b348-40fdb3c3d9a6" where cdbid="343f34be-b1cf-4cdf-8c35-344847a13837"; 
update db01.CONTENT set locationid ="72d799e8-ff97-4388-a498-47badd6ca7d8" where cdbid="54b0623f-b5f0-47a1-bf90-9c8cb2054676"; 
update db01.CONTENT set locationid ="72d799e8-ff97-4388-a498-47badd6ca7d8" where cdbid="8056e400-b809-4e08-bf0a-d5370f3e1b44";
```

I tried some things trying to combine

```
for file in ./output/*;
do
  echo ${file##*/}
done
```

and

```
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line"]];
do
  #awk stuff
done <"$1"
```

But I couldn't get any result. all help is appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46891182/edit) to include more information (although I certainly appreciate the detail of your post so far!).  Are you open to perl or other tools?

Comment: Why are you building a CSV to process with `awk`?  It seems like you could generate the SQL script directly by the same means and without much more effort.

Answer (score 1):

One solution using pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) :

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ./output
for file in *; do
    while read -r line; do
        echo 'update db01.CONTENT set locationid="'$file'" where cdbid ="'$line'";'
    done < $file
done
```

### Output :

```
update db01.CONTENT set locationid="3afb6dad-352d-4c2a-b348-40fdb3c3d9a6" where cdbid ="019f08dd-5017-43a1-b65b-c77cb90068ab";
update db01.CONTENT set locationid="3afb6dad-352d-4c2a-b348-40fdb3c3d9a6" where cdbid ="0479c914-6988-4038-ac74-f5b4adb123d0";
update db01.CONTENT set locationid="3afb6dad-352d-4c2a-b348-40fdb3c3d9a6" where cdbid ="05a6b05a-dff9-4f7c-8a7e-92c8651b8cde";
update db01.CONTENT set locationid="3afb6dad-352d-4c2a-b348-40fdb3c3d9a6" where cdbid ="05ad4a6a-e2c6-4074-adfd-0899c15a3600";
update db01.CONTENT set locationid="3afb6dad-352d-4c2a-b348-40fdb3c3d9a6" where cdbid ="204b12af-42d8-48a0-83c6-10e02a051ed5";
update db01.CONTENT set locationid="3afb6dad-352d-4c2a-b348-40fdb3c3d9a6" where cdbid ="20c4fb93-6ed2-4dee-87da-749b52c76d74";
update db01.CONTENT set locationid="3afb6dad-352d-4c2a-b348-40fdb3c3d9a6" where cdbid ="27b2552a-1050-47fb-96fe-714b4231a067";
update db01.CONTENT set locationid="3afb6dad-352d-4c2a-b348-40fdb3c3d9a6" where cdbid ="343f34be-b1cf-4cdf-8c35-344847a13837";
update db01.CONTENT set locationid="72d799e8-ff97-4388-a498-47badd6ca7d8" where cdbid ="54b0623f-b5f0-47a1-bf90-9c8cb2054676";
update db01.CONTENT set locationid="72d799e8-ff97-4388-a498-47badd6ca7d8" where cdbid ="8056e400-b809-4e08-bf0a-d5370f3e1b44";
```

Comment: Hi Gilles, Thanks for the info! I get an empty locationid="" When I execute this code. The cdbid is correctly parsed, though. Any thoughts? should I replace $i with something else?

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

based on your input/output file format

```
$ awk '{file=FILENAME; sub(".*/", "", file);
        print "update db01.CONTENT set locationid=\"" file 
              "\" where cdbid=\"" $1 "\""}' output/*
```

Answer (score 0):

Not `awk`, but here's a [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) one-liner:

```
 perl -ne 'chomp; print "update db01.CONTENT set locationid=\"$ARGV\" where cdbid=\"$_\";\n";' * > whatever.sql
```

#### Testing

I made a test directory with two files having the following contents:

in1: (analogous to `3afb6dad-352d-4c2a-b348-40fdb3c3d9a6`)

```
out1         (analogous to 019f08dd-5017-43a1-b65b-c77cb90068ab)
out2         (analogous to 0479c914-6988-4038-ac74-f5b4adb123d0)
```

in2: (analogous to `72d799e8-ff97-4388-a498-47badd6ca7d8`)

```
out3         (analogous to 54b0623f-b5f0-47a1-bf90-9c8cb2054676)
out4         (analogous to 8056e400-b809-4e08-bf0a-d5370f3e1b44)
```

When I run the above with Perl 5.22, I get:

```
update db01.CONTENT set locationid="in1" where cdbid="out1";
update db01.CONTENT set locationid="in1" where cdbid="out2";
update db01.CONTENT set locationid="in2" where cdbid="out3";
update db01.CONTENT set locationid="in2" where cdbid="out4";
```

which I think is analogous to what you want.

#### Explanation

**Edit** The `-n` switch provides a `while(<>){ ... }` around the given command. 
 Therefore, perl processes each file given on the command line, one line at a time.  Within the script (the implicit loop body), `$_` is the line, and `$ARGV` is the name of the file it came from ([reference](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Variables-related-to-filehandles)).  `chomp` removes the trailing newline from `$_`, and then the `print` statement outputs the SQL you want.  All the output is saved by the shell into `whatever.sql`.

Comment: Why not using `-n` switch instead of `while(<>)` ?

Comment: @GillesQuenot Because I didn't think of it ;) .  Edited --- thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote in comments, creating a CSV intermediate file just to consume with `awk` is pretty pointless.  If you can create such a file then you can create the wanted SQL script directly, too.  For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in ./output/*;
do
  location=$(basename "$file")
  while read cb <"$file"; do
    echo "update db01.CONTENT set locationid=\"${location}\" where cdbid =\"${cb}\";"
  done
done
```

That version writes the result to standard output.  You can redirect it where you want, or else put the desired redirection into the script.

Comment: Hi John, thank you for your help! 
The csv method is my old method. I gather a bunch of UUID's  and put them into a csv. However, I now have another script that makes me a file per  $1 listing all the variables needed to match with $1 

I think something is still wrong with the script you provided. When I only have 1 file containing only one line, the script keeps running endlessly generating the same sql query over and over

eg. file 72d799e8-ff97-4388-a498-47badd6ca7d8 today is the only file containing only one line:
54b0623f-b5f0-47a1-bf90-9c8cb2054676